# databricks Python notebook from azure data factory or locally if statement

Tags: python, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I have a Databricks Python notebook that reads in a parameter from ADF using:

```
Program_Name = dbutils.widgets.get("Program_Name")
```

Is there an IF statement or something similar I can do in the notebook code, such that when I run the notebook interactively, it will substitute the call to dbutils with a plain assignment?  Logically I want something like:

```
if running in ADF:
   Program_Name = dbutils.widgets.get("Program_Name")
else:
   Program_Name = 'ABC123'
```

If such a thing is possible, it beats the alternative of having to comment out the dbutils call every time I modify the rest of the notebook :)  I've done similar things so that a script can be run from Jupyter/PyCharm or from the command line, but am not aware of anything that tells the python interpreter it's been called from ADF.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of catching up exception, it's just easier to create widget explicitly, and set default value (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#widget-utilities)).

```py
dbutils.widgets.text("Program_Name", "ABC123", "Program name")
Program_Name = dbutils.widgets.get("Program_Name")
```

This has following benefits:

1. The code is simpler - you don't need to have do any try/catch
2. If necessary you can pass another program name even if you run notebook interactively

Comment: :  That's a *really* cool trick!  Interactive parameters in a notebook = awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You could call the notebook with a prefix when running it from ADF.
For example, you would call the notebook with `Program_Name = "ADF_prog_name"`

```py
Program_Name = dbutils.widgets.get("Program_Name")
if not(Program_Name.contains('ADF')):
   Program_Name = 'ABC123'
```

Comment: Thanks Axel:  Problem is the call to dbutils throws an error so the "if" statement never gets run - but that made me realize it's an error, not a crash.  If you want to edit your answer, the strategy works as a try-except instead of an "if" statement.  Your answer still lead me to the solution!